# How to integrate libcreate in an own ros package - (turtlebot1)

Tags: ros, roomba, create-autonomy, roomba-500-series

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey there,

what I recently did was installing [a ROS driver for a roomba 521](https://github.com/AutonomyLab/create_autonomy) (similar to a turtlebot1). I cloned this files in my catkin_ws/src/create_autonomy and then I just catkin_make them. All works fine. Now what I found out is that this ROS driver relies on a  [libcreate library](https://github.com/AutonomyLab/libcreate). This library is however build in catkin_ws/devel/src/libcreate.

What I want to do next is create an own package (e.g: catkin_ws/src/roomba_521) and in this package I would like to have some c++ files which somehow include this library, so that I can use functions etc.

(1) That is why I would like to ask **how and where** do I have to install  the [libcreate library](https://github.com/AutonomyLab/libcreate)

(2) How do I have to reference to this library e.g. in a c++ file / just include these files?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249142/how-to-integrate-libcreate-in-an-own-ros-package---(turtlebot1)/) by [Markus](https://answers.ros.org/users/26348/markus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 311 on 2016-11-30

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Usui](https://answers.ros.org/users/36306/usui/) on 2019-06-23**:
Wait, catkin_ws/devel/ only has include, lib, and share. Where is the src? Also how did you link libcreate and create_autonomy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use [this dev branch of create_autonomy](https://github.com/autonomylab/create_autonomy/) (**EDIT: merged**) as a reference. This assumes that libcreate is installed as a catkin package (currently by cloning libcreate into your workspace and building with catkin). Then, in your package.xml you can add build/run dependencies to libcreate, include/link in your CMakeLists.txt ([example](https://github.com/AutonomyLab/create_autonomy/blob/90e597ea4d85cde1ec32a1d43ea2dd0b4cbf481c/ca_driver/CMakeLists.txt)), and include the header `create/create.h` and make API calls in your code ([example](https://github.com/AutonomyLab/create_autonomy/blob/90e597ea4d85cde1ec32a1d43ea2dd0b4cbf481c/ca_driver/include/create_driver/create_driver.h#L36)). Hope it helps.

---

Originally posted by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) with karma: 1870 on 2016-12-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Markus](https://answers.ros.org/users/26348/markus/) on 2016-12-02**:
Thanks Jacob ;) that was easier as I thought! I got it.
I also would like to use your code and libcreate library for my own project which is specefic for the roomba 521. Do I have your permission to create an own github repository witch contains code that is very similar to yours?

**Comment by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) on 2016-12-02**:
Yes, as long as you adhere to the [3-clause BSD](https://opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause) license. Is there a core feature that **create_autonomy** is missing that you cannot just use that?

**Comment by [Markus](https://answers.ros.org/users/26348/markus/) on 2016-12-03**:
No your code is working perfect. Anyway I just would like to experiment a little bit with it and simply git clone this modified code that is why I am thinking about making my own repository. I hope this is ok for you? Anyway I found out that I am not able to execute dual processes on the roomba.

**Comment by [Markus](https://answers.ros.org/users/26348/markus/) on 2016-12-03**:
Dual Processes on the roomba: I was for example not able to simultanously play a song and change the colour of the power clean led light.

**Comment by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) on 2016-12-03**:
OK. If you end up improving the functionality of the driver, pull requests are welcome :)

**Comment by [Markus](https://answers.ros.org/users/26348/markus/) on 2016-12-05**:
of course I will let you know if I have something.

**Comment by [Usui](https://answers.ros.org/users/36306/usui/) on 2019-06-23**:
@jacobperron your links doesn't lead to any page. Could you re upload it?

**Comment by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) on 2019-07-02**:
@Usui updated.